# MonoTouch: NSData memory conservation

Tags: ios4, xamarin.ios

Does anyone know if it's more memory-efficient to use NSData.FromFile or FromStream vs filling an NSData.FromArray? My specific case is that I'm sending a large file via email (MFMailComposeViewController.AddAttachmentData). Right now I'm filling an NSData with the bytes that I want to send, but I was hoping that if I use NSData.FromFile or FromStream, it wouldn't ever keep ALL the file data in memory at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck here. If you pass data on to `AddAttachmentData()`, the mail composer will most probably copy the bytes and hold them in memory (you should see from Instruments). Best you can do is to `Dispose()` your `NSData` as soon as you passed it on to release memory as fast as possible.